# Insert/update/delete many documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I want to do crud operations on about 1000 documents.

using a loop and insert 1 by 1 is fine, but there is a better aka faster way?

like for example in **Postgres** I can use generate_series() for that purpose, and what about Mongo?

Comment: In what format are these 1000 documents you want to insert into a MongoDB collection?

Comment: You can use [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html) _or_ in case your input data is in JSON or CSV format you can use `mongoimport` utility. You can explore [Collection methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-collection/).

Comment: a simple format actually : {"name": "Gal", "hobbies": ["reading", "gaming"]} I just want to insert same row 1000 times

Answer (score 2):

As prasad wrote in the comments above, you can use [insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html).  You would write a loop to generate the documents and store them in an array.  Then you could pass that array of documents to db.collection.insertMany().

Another option would be to use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite). You could write a loop to generate an array of the operations you want to insert. For example:

```
[ 
    { insertOne: { "document": { "name": "Gal", "hobbies": ["reading", "gaming"     ] } } },
    { insertOne: { "document": { "name": "Gal", "hobbies": ["reading", "gaming" ] } } },
    ... 
]
```

Then you would pass that array to bulkWrite:

```
try {
   db.characters.bulkWrite(myArray);
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks, Lauren, and idea what operation (bulkWrite or insertmany) is better from a performance perspective?

Comment: insertMany() is a wrapper on top of bulkWrite(), so the performance is the same.